# What is the safest way to get a newer version of a repo from yum on Amazon Linux?

Tags: yum, binutils, amazon-linux, amazon-linux-2

I need a newer version of binutils on Amazon Linux to compile a piece of needed software. This is due to a bug in version 2.29 which is the latest available in their repo. What would be the best way to add another repo, and will this mess up future uses of the yum command as I add and remove non-approved repos? Can I just add in a repo from a similar flavor like CentOS? Does Amazon have a less "Safe" version that has up to date software in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me the safest way to get newer version on your VM is to compile it and install it in different place like `/opt/binutils` or `/usr/local/binutils` and use absolute paths for utils.